# How many kinds of Distance Function can we use?

Tags: machine-learning, metrics, distance, similarity

I was reading stuffs about pattern recognition. Recently I want to make a survey of methods to evaluate similarities of vectors. As far as I know, there are Euclidean distances, Mahalanobis distances and Cosine Distance. Can anyone present some more names or keywords to search?

Answer (score 4):

Also mutual neighbor distance (MND), Minkowski metric, Hausdorff distance, conceptual similarity, normalized Google distance, KL divergence, Spearman’s rank correlation, and Lin similarity.  (Not all of these are vector based.)

I highly recommend [Pattern Classification](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471056693) by Duda, Hart, and Stork for further reading.  It is extensively cited.

Answer (score 3):

Pearson, Manhatten, Gower, Jaccard, Tanimoto, Russel Rao, Dice, Kulczynski, Simple Matching, Levenshtein

Comment: Good points, but only a few of them are vector-based distance function.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own distance metrics too, so I would say there can be A LOT of possible distance metrics. Now if those metrics are good or have any meaning is another story.

Answer (score 1):

Hamming distance